# How to map attribute as Class and Id in DB with JPA2.0

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a model, that each class extends Entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now, in my model, each Entity could have an attribute:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Attribute extends Entity {
    private Entity entity;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My question is: How can I map entity attribute of class Attribute ? My idea is to store this attribute as entityClass and entityId, but still I don't know how to achieve this with JPA?

---

Example of concrete class that extends Entity:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Ball extends Entity {
    private Set<Attribute> attributes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entity")
    public Set<Attribute> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Set<Attribute> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean it has a 1-1 relation with some other Entity

Comment: no, there is 1-* relationship. For example: I have entity Ball -> Ball extends Entity and Ball has an attribute Set<Attribute> attributes. So I need bidirectional relationship between Attribute and Entity(Ball)

Comment: This sounds like a horrible thing to do. What's your end goal? How would you like it to be stored in the database?

Comment: As I wrote I my question I want to store it in one table called 'Attribute' where the entity will be stored as concrete class name and it's id ? Why horrible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this in JPA.  You could map the relationship as @Transient and add tow @Basic mappings for the id and class (perhaps using property get/set method).  Then execute the query in you model code.

If you are using EclipseLink you may be able to use a @VariableOneToOne,

See,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_variableonetoone.htm#CHDDFDGF

Comment: Yes EclipseLink is an interesting option here. I read a little and I found @Transformation Annotation which could be useful here. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

According your comments you need a bidirectional relationship in your mapped superclass. Unfortunately, you cannot do that in JPA. The reason is that a `MappedSuperClass` is not an entity and fields of `MappedSuperClass` belongs to different sub-classes.

Source [JPA 2.0 Specs](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) (2.11.2)

(I don't know exactelly what your trying to do but: )
It seems your are trying to persist the metamodel of your persistence model. If you need to read it: you can use [`EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#getMetamodel%28%29)

Comment: Well not exactly in mapped superclass. I just add an example to my question, how could be implemented some concrete class that extends my Entity.